# SWIFT - Storyboard instantiating from Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I'm translating an old app made in Objective-C to the new SWIFT 2.0 language, but I'm having some hard time in this particular line of code:

```
UIStoryboard *sdkStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"thirdParty.MySDK"]];
```

The problem lies in the "bundle" part, I made many researches but none of them could do the trick, as most of the examples found were to "bundle: nil"

This is what I could do by now:

```
let sdkStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: ???)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle(identifier: "thirdParty.MySDK"))
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! I was using "path:" instead of "identifier:"

Answer (score 0):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thirdParty.MySDK") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
let Bundlepath = NSBundle(identifier: "thirdParty.MySDK")
let sdkStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: Bundlepath )
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! I was using "path:" instead of "identifier:"